# nginx-ingress displays 404 page

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, nginx-ingress

I have an EKS cluster that I inherited (no documentation).  The cluster hadnt been upgraded in years.  I was tasked to upgrade it.  The version on nginx-ingress was from quay.io which is no longer maintained.  I was able to upgrade the cluster to 1.23 and installed the official nginx-ingress version.  I got the helm values before deleting the old Ingress and I applied the same values to the new ingress. The problem I am having now is that all the page hosts are displaying 404 not found.  The ingress is pointing to an HAProxy which in turn talks to the application.  When I hop on to the new ingress pod and I curl one of the hosts, curl goes back out and in and I again get the 404 not found.  But when I curl one of the redirects on the HAProxy from the same ingress box, I get the site.

It seem to be the way the new ingress is trying to talk to the HAProxy.  I have not redeployed the HA proxy because it seems to be working on 1.23.  Also the HAProxy does not have logging turned on, so I cant see any logs.
(I dont want to redesign this cluster until it is fully upgraded.  There are plenty of things I would change on here.)
Questions.

1. Is there an easy way to turn logging on on the HAProxy?
2. What other troubleshooting steps could I do to figure out what is wrong with this ingress controller?